# Something strange with Stack Overflow summary popup

Tags: support, user-card

I found something strange with my Stack Overflow account. When I open the summary window it show me reputation for day = 0, for week it show 89 and for month it shows just 64.

**My question is:** How is it possible that the week reputation is greater than the month?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the new month *just* started, and the ***week*** started last month.

More specifically, the week started on Sep 29, 2013, and the new month obviously started on October 1st. This indicates that there are 2 days of activity between the week and the new month - ie, Sep 29/30.

I *currently* have a week reputation of 344, and a month reputation of 10 - simply because I either earned my rep on Sep 29 or 30.

Comment: `@JoshC` thanks i got your point...